# Ads overlapping bottom navigation in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, admob

i have setup banner ads in flutter and those are overlapping the bottom navigation bar

[image: This is how it looks]

I want to display ads below that bottom navigation bar,

is there any way that i can add a margin below the bottom navigation bar ?

i have implemented ads in home.dart (mainpage)

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../../ui/widgets/bottom_nav_bar.dart';
import '../../core/utils/theme.dart';
import 'search_page.dart';
import 'category.dart';
import 'main_page.dart';
import 'settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';
import 'for_you.dart';

const String AD_MOB_APP_ID = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713';
const String AD_MOB_TEST_DEVICE = 'DEC3010B2445165B43EB949F5D97D0F8 - run ad then check device logs for value';
const String AD_MOB_AD_ID = 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}


class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

BannerAd _bannerAd;

  static final MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = new MobileAdTargetingInfo(
    testDevices: <String>[AD_MOB_TEST_DEVICE],
  );

  BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return new BannerAd(
      adUnitId: AD_MOB_AD_ID,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
    );
  }

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  final PageController _pageController = PageController();




  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


  }



  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final stateData = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
    final ThemeData state = stateData.getTheme();


FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: AD_MOB_APP_ID);
    _bannerAd = createBannerAd()..load()..show();
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        backgroundColor: state.primaryColor,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'RevWalls',
          style: state.textTheme.headline,
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: state.textTheme.body1.color,
            ),
            onPressed: () => showSearch(
                context: context, delegate: WallpaperSearch(themeData: state)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: state.primaryColor,
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          children: <Widget>[
            MainBody(),
            Category(),
            ForYou(),
            SettingsPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),



      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        unselectedColor: state.textTheme.body1.color,
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
        },
        selectedColor: state.accentColor,
        backgroundColor: state.primaryColor,
        showElevation: false,
        items: [
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.category),
            title: Text('Subreddits'),
          ),
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.phone_android),
            title: Text('Exact Fit'),
          ),
          BottomNavyBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget oldBody(ThemeData state) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool boxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: state.primaryColor,
            elevation: 4,
            title: Text(
              'reWalls',
              style: state.textTheme.headline,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: state.accentColor),
                onPressed: () {
                  showSearch(
                      context: context,
                      delegate: WallpaperSearch(themeData: state));
                },
              )
            ],
            floating: true,
            pinned: _selectedIndex == 0 ? false : true,
            snap: false,
            centerTitle: false,
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: Container(
        color: state.primaryColor,
        child: PageView(
          controller: _pageController,
          onPageChanged: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = index;
            });
          },
          children: <Widget>[
            MainBody(),
            Category(),
            ForYou(),
            SettingsPage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is the bottom navigation bar -

```
library bottom_navy_bar;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class BottomNavyBar extends StatelessWidget {

  final int selectedIndex;
  final double iconSize;
  final Color backgroundColor, selectedColor, unselectedColor;
  final bool showElevation;
  final Duration animationDuration;
  final List<BottomNavyBarItem> items;
  final ValueChanged<int> onItemSelected;

  BottomNavyBar(
      {Key key,
      this.selectedIndex = 0,
      this.showElevation = true,
      this.iconSize = 20,
      this.backgroundColor,
      this.selectedColor,
      this.unselectedColor,
      this.animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
      @required this.items,
      @required this.onItemSelected}) {
    assert(items != null);
    assert(items.length >= 2 && items.length <= 5);
    assert(onItemSelected != null);
  }


  Widget _buildItem(BottomNavyBarItem item, bool isSelected) {



    return AnimatedContainer(
      width: isSelected ? 120 : 50,
      height: double.maxFinite,
      duration: animationDuration,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isSelected ? selectedColor.withOpacity(0.2) : backgroundColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100.0)),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                child: IconTheme(
                  data: IconThemeData(
                      size: iconSize,
                      color: isSelected ? selectedColor : unselectedColor),
                  child: item.icon,
                ),
              ),
              isSelected
                  ? DefaultTextStyle.merge(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: selectedColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      child: item.title,
                    )
                  : SizedBox.shrink()
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 55,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: items.map((item) {
            var index = items.indexOf(item);
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                onItemSelected(index);
              },
              child: _buildItem(item, selectedIndex == index),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavyBarItem {
  final Icon icon;
  final Text title;

  BottomNavyBarItem({
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.title,
  }) {
    assert(icon != null);
    assert(title != null);
  }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer myself

We can use this to set margin in a container with other things like height, width

This code will add margin to bottom of bottom nav bar, as per my need i want to show ads below navbar so this solves my problem

```
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

adding   *builder* like this will solve the problem

```
var paddingBottom = 60.0;
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//
return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'World General info',
    //theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.cyan,),
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.cyan,
      accentColor: Colors.green,
      textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText2: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
    ),
    home: MyHomePage(title: 'World General Info'),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return new Padding(
        child: child,
        padding:  EdgeInsets.only(bottom: paddingBottom),
      );
    }
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MediaQuery.of(context) for that.
Wrap the whole Code inside a Container of height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 60 . (the height of ad)

```
Column(
    children: [
                 Container(
                     height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 60,
                     child: HomePage(),
                    ),
                 BannerAd(),
              ]
);
```

Comment: No it doesn't help, but i got solution

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your scaffold

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    height: 50.0,
    color: Colors.white,
),
```

Answer (score -1):

Think Simplest bro  ... wrap your column ( mainAxisSize : MainAxisSize.min )

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: _appBar,
    body: _body,
    bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              height: 70,
              child: Center(child: Text('Banner'))),
          BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), label: 'Add'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), label: 'Add'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), label: 'Add')
            ],
          )
        ]))
```